# Using a WCF Service to create a Linked Table in MS Access

Tags: wcf, ms-access, wcf-binding, linked-tables

<**Updated**>

I wrote a `WCF Service` based on `netTcpBinding` that get its data from SQL Server, Is there any way to consume these data in MS Access?
In the other word I want to create a read-only `Linked Table` using this service, in `MS Access`

`Linked Table` means me a table that get its data from an external source(in my case from WCF Service).

<**Updated/**>

My service has a method:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
```

that `Person` is:

```
public class Person
{
   public int {get;set;}
   public FirstName {get;set;}
   public LastName {get;set;}
}
```

I want to have a read-only `Linked Table` in `MS Access`, with above data(data that return from `GetPeople()`), I want to join the `Linked Table` with my other tables to create a new `Query`.

Comment: So you want a wcf with an access database as backend? Please put more details into your question. It's very vague.

Comment: Well, it's still not much clearer to me (especially what _linked table_ means to you and where your "other tables" reside) but if your question is whether or not it's possible to have an access db as backend, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @khlr: The question updated.